# How to avoid N+1 queries in rails dependent destroy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, associations, eager-loading, destroy

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
end

Class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

When a User having N posts is destroyed, N+1 queries are run to destroy the associated posts and the user. How to avoid eager loading in this case?

Comment: Depends on whether you really need to call `destroy` on every post. You can use `dependen: :delete_all` and it will delete all posts as one SQL query, but no callbacks will be called (eg. before_destroy or after_destroy) on deleted posts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
dependent: delete_all
```

which creates a single SQL query to delete the associated records, but any `before_destroy` `after_destroy` callbacks will not be called as no `destroy` method is going to be called.

If you're using Postgres you will need to pass the cascade flag in your origin migration on the foreign key for this to work

```
add_foreign_key :some_table, :related_table, on_delete: cascade
```